# Magnetic field far away from circular loop

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Suppose we have a current (clockwise) loop in the xy-plane. I can describe the field in the z-axis, above the center of the loop (Griffiths eq 5.41).

But I want to know the magnetic field a) close to the loop b) far away from the loop, in the plane of the loop (so the xy-plane).

For a) I can just say that close to the loop you are approximately looking at a straight wire. But I'm slightly confused for b). To me it seems like far away from the current of the loop will be zero. Since far away the current at point A will be canceled by the current at A−180∘.

Is this idea correct and is there a mathematical way to describe the field for situation b)?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Biot-Savart law to calculate the field? Yes, very close to the loop you could approximate the field as that due to an infinite straight wire. Far away from the loop, there isn't an exact cancellation. If you are far enough away, the magnetic field will be approximated very well by that of a [magnetic dipole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole#External_magnetic_field_produced_by_a_magnetic_dipole_moment), decaying as $1/r^3$.

Comment: That's for far away in the z-axis (centered in the middle). But I'm asking for far away in the xy-plane

Comment: Why do you think the magnetic dipole approximation doesn't work in the xy-plane?

Comment: I checked analytically and it turns out that you are correct. However I'm a bit puzzled why this is true. It seems like the field in the z direction decays with $1/r^3$ but the radial field is exactly zero. Do the x and y components of the field cancel out exactly? I know they do at z=0 but I don't understand why they would cancel far away

Comment: This is not because of any cancellation. According to the Biot-Savart law, the magnetic field contribution of each piece of the loop is in the direction of $d\vec\ell\times\vec r$, which is along $z$ because $d\vec\ell$ and $\vec r$ both lie in the xy-plane. You can also see by sketching the magnetic field lines (or looking at those of a magnetic dipole) that there can be no radial field in the xy-plane.